# Why is my enemy kill code not working?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I'm trying to make an enemy for my game, and everything works, except for the bit of code where the enemy is supposed to die.

My player attacks but nothing happens.

I filled in the prefabs, I have the right tags, I tried remaking it and I can't find anything that is wrong.

---

What am I doing wrong?

```
#pragma strict
var EnemyItself : GameObject;
var EnemyCorpse : GameObject;

function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Hero Punch") {
        EnemyItself.SetActive(false);
        EnemyCorpse.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, indicate what "does not work". Is the collision detected ? Is the condition called ? Add some Debug.Log to determine where does the error come from.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

As previously pointed out, through comments, there is nothing wrong with your code. Assuming you have referenced the game objects and are using tags correctly, the only thing left appears to be your rigidbody.

This also seems to be the confirmed issue, in the comments.

---

Collision events require *at least* one of the game objects to contain a `RigidBody` component. Ideally, these would be on the *moving objects*, and we would not have a situation where *two non-moving objects* enter a collision event.

It is also worth mentioning that you need to use `RigidBody` for 3D collion events, where 2D collision events will require a `RigidBody2D`.